# HTML/CSS select option disabled color

Tags: html, css

I am having a weird CSS issue. I have a dropdown with a disabled option and other options, when I click on the arrow thing and the dropdown expands the color of the disabled option appears grey and isn't readable ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI4qu.jpg)), and when I hover the mouse over an option which isn't disabled the disabled option is visible ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p85gU.jpg)). The disabled option is visible when I hover because I have `select option:disabled { color: #f1f1f1; }` in my CSS, is there any way to use the same color for the disabled option when I am not hovering over any of the other options.

Comment: Can you include the rest of your styling so that we may see what other styles are being rendered?

Comment: There's too much code in my CSS but I can share the GitHub repository link - https://github.com/The-Aasha-Initiative/The-Aasha-Initiative.github.io

Comment: Please select the code needed to produce a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and embed it into your question. The issue with external links to code is that code changes and when it no longer reflects your problem here, it makes this discussion not useful for future readers.